# Android's Home Dialog

Tags: android, dialog

If I install more than two launchers on Android,
everytime I pressed the Home button,
a dialog appears as follows.

```
╭──────────────────────────────────╮
│@ Complete action using            │
├───────────────────────────────────┤
│▓▓ Launcher                        │
├───────────────────────────────────┤
│▓▓ ADW Launcher                    │
├───────────────────────────────────┤
│□ Use by default for this action   │  ←← I want this
╰──────────────────────────────────╯
```

I use setAdapter() to add a list of items to AlertDialog,
but I also wanna add something at the bottom of the dialog, 
like mentioned above.

Is it possible to achieve that without defining a custom layout for Dialog ?

Comment: "Is it possible to achieve that without defining a custom layout for Dialog ? " - you know the answer. NO :-)

Comment: +1 for the clear ASCII drawing. No, as far as I know this is not possible without a custom dialog layout.

Answer (score 0):

It is a hack, but it might be possible. Basically, you want to add your bottom line as the last item in the list, and implement an on click handler to modify the list and show the check mark as a character. This does go against the framework. Just bite the bullet and add your custom layout ...